# how to show and hide element inside a single div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a weird case that I need help.

I am trying to hide and show certain stuff when user clicks a button.

My html

```
   <div class='slide-content'>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <div class='title-bar'>
            sub title here
            <div class='edit-container'>
                <a class='edit' href='#'>Edit</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id='content' class='details'>
            <div class='contents'>
                 <p>contents here</p>
            </div>
            <div class='break'></div>
        </div>
        <div id='edit-content' class='content-details'>
             <div class='contents'>
                <div class='editable-content'>
                    contents here…...                          
                </div>
            </div>             
            <div class='break'></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='slide-content'>
     …...
```

another 10 slide-contents divs…

jquery

```
   $('.edit').on('click', function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
       if($(this).text()=='Edit'){
           $(this).text('Done');
           $(this).closest('.slide-content').find($('.content-details')).show();
           $(this).closest('.slide-content').find($('.details')).hide();
       }else{
           $(this).text('Edit');
           $(this).closest('.slide-content').find($('.content-details')).hide();
           $(this).closest('.slide-content').find($('.details').show());
       }
   })
});
```

css

```
.content-details{
  display:none;
}
```

My problem is, when I click the `edit` button first time, it shows my `.content-details` and hide `.detail` div. However, when I click the `edit` button again, it show every `.details` div in my page (even it's under different `.slide-content` div). My intension is to show only 1 `.detail` div under current `.slide-content.`

I am not sure what happen here. Can anyone help me out on this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't closing your parentheses properly:

```
$(this).closest('.slide-content').find($('.details').show());
```

To see the problem more clearly:

```
$(this).closest('.slide-content').find(
    $('.details').show()
);
```

so you are explicitly calling `$('.details').show()`.

You want this:

```
$(this).closest('.slide-content').find($('.details')).show();
```

But actually, you don't need a jquery object for `find()`, so this works just as well (here, and the other places you are using this pattern):

```
$(this).closest('.slide-content').find('.details').show();
```

Also, as a final note, I think it would be good to simplify your code and use a little caching:

```
$('.edit').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text($this.text() == 'Edit' ? 'Done' : 'Edit');
    $this.closest('.slide-content').find('.content-details, .details').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is all you need: http://jsbin.com/IsUQaJA/1/edit

```
$('.edit').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();   
       var txt = $(this).text();
       $(this).text(txt=='Edit'?'Done':'Edit').closest('.slide-content')
              .find('.details, .content-details').toggle();
});
```